# How to split an element in a list into two elements?

Tags: python, regex, list

I want to split elements of list, each element is currently made up of a movie and a date, however I now need to separate them so I can add them to a database

This is what I've tried

```
movies=["The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales (English subtitles)('23rd', 'May')"]
```

```
splitter=re.compile('(/(.+)').split
[part for img in movies for part in splitter(img) if part]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could yo show us any  code attempt you made?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what format you were hoping to get the elements into, but you could take hone in on similarities, like if each date starts with "('".

```
movies = ["The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales (English subtitles) ('23rd','May')"]
titles,dates = [],[]

for i in range(len(movies)):
    newTitle,newDate,sign,count = "","",False,0

    for char in movies[i]:
        if char == "(":
            sign = True
        elif sign == True:
            if char == "'":
                newDate += "(" + movies[i][count:]
                break
        else:
            newTitle += char
        count += 1
    titles.append(newTitle)
    dates.append(newDate)

print(titles)
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales ']

["('23rd','May')"]
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hey thanks that worked perfectly really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there ;D

```
import re

movies=["The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales (English subtitles)('23rd', 'May')"]

matcher = re.compile(r"^(.*)\((.*?)\)$").match

print([matcher(movie).groups() for movie in movies])
```

I suggest using [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to learn and test regular expressions.

Comment: thanks although I didn't want may and 23rd to be in separate elements this was still helpful

Comment: Done! Just a slight change

Answer (score 1):

We can use three important python functions for this problem:
 `replace(pattern, replacement)` 
`string[start_position:end_position]` and `string.index(pattern)`

```
movies=["The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales (English subtitles)('23rd', 'May')"]
```

First, make 2 patterns which denote the beginning and end of the date area:

```
date_start = "('"
date_end = "')"
```

Then, remove that part of the string for further analysis:

```
date_information = movies[0][movies[0].index(date_start):movies[0].index(date_end)]
```

At this point, "date information" should be `('23rd', 'May`

Then, just trim the first 2 characters and replace the single quotations:

```
date_information = date_information[2:].replace("'", "")
```

This will give you a final string, "date_information" which should be the date and the month, separated by a comma:

```
23rd, May
```

Finally, you can split this string by comma (`date_information.split(",")`) to get it into a database.

Comment: how would I retain just the name aswell?

Comment: `name_information = movies[0][0:movies[0].index(date_start)]` should give you the movie name (between 0 and the open parenthesis before "23rd".)  Thank you for the follow-up question.  I know it's not regex-based, but it's one way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regex, you can use `split`

```
movies=["The Big Bad Fox and Other Tales (English subtitles)('23rd', 'May')"]
splitter= movies[0].split(')(')
movie_name = f"{splitter[0]})"
date = f"({splitter[1]}"
```

this is parsing so, keep in mind this will only work in this standard format.

Comment: When trying this I get an index error saying date= f"({splitter[1]}"
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This sample is splitting by )(, if you have blank space between them it may cause. This error means its not string is not splitted.